# Cannot justify constraints in explicitly typed binding error

Tags: haskell

I've made this function is Haskell:

```
countOccurrences :: t -> [t] -> Int
countOccurrences x [] = 0
countOccurrences x (a:b)    |x == a = 1 + (countOccurrences x b)
                            |otherwise = countOccurrences x b
```

And I receive the following error:

```
ERROR file:{Hugs}\packages\hugsbase\Hugs.hs:38 - Cannot justify
constraints in explicitly typed binding
*** Expression    : countOccurrences
*** Type          : a -> [a] -> Int
*** Given context : ()
*** Constraints   : Eq a
```

However, if I comment the first line, the function works perfectly:

```
--countOccurrences :: t -> [t] -> Int
countOccurrences x [] = 0
countOccurrences x (a:b)    |x == a = 1 + (countOccurrences x b)
                            |otherwise = countOccurrences x b
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you specify the type signature of `t -> [t] -> Int`, the compiler can't align this with what it infers of `Eq t => t -> [t] -> Int`.  The constraint of `Eq t` is very important, since you're using `x == a` in the definition of your function.  The only way to use `==` is if the values you're comparing implement `Eq`.  By telling the compiler explicitly that your type does not necessarily implement `Eq`, it can't type check.

By deleting the type signature, you allow the compiler to infer the type entirely by itself.  If you load your file in Hugs or GHCi, you can check the type of the function and you'll see that the compiler infers the `Eq t` constraint.

Comment: If I wanted to maintain the signature, what should I then do to make it work?

Comment: Simply write it as `countOccurrences :: Eq t => t -> [t] -> Int`, so that you're telling the compiler than you can only count the number of instances of an element in a list if you know how to tell if the elements are equal.